# Box shape for diminished scale on bass guitar

Tags: scales, bass-guitar

Does anyone have a box shape for a diminished scale so I can find it quicker on the fretboard?

Comment: My tip for visualizing the half-whole diminished scale starting on the fifth of a scale, i.e. how you might use it over a dominant-seventh chord: it "forks" the tonic (i.e. the note where the dominant would lead to) from both sides, but skipping over it. For example the G half-whole diminished scale, the frets are on the E string: 3, 4, 6, but on the A string: 2, 4, 5, ... so it skips over the 3rd fret on the A string, which would be a C, i.e. the target for a G dominant in a V - I motion. The same principle of skipping over the "target tonic" applies everywhere on the fretboard, of course.

Comment: There are *two* diminished scales - the whole/half and the half/whole. Add to that the diminished seventh arpeggio.

Comment: @Tim Really, there is one diminished scale, but two modes.

Answer (score 8):

My shape for diminished scales is a parallelogram, not a box. Box shapes are awkward for diminished scales because of the proximity of the notes. Here is a simple hand sketched diagram. This scale shows the starting notes for both whole/half and half/whole steps:

[image]

An easy fingering approach to this is 1-1 3 4 on each string ascending and the reverse descending. If one really wanted to do a more vertical box shaped diminished scale it would be 6 frets wide. This is easier, more practical and has a bit more range.

EDIT: Here is the more vertical box shape I mentioned earlier, just take out the yellow highlighted notes from the original and play the red ones instead. It involves playing 3 diagonal half step pairs in a row from the A to G strings and is harder to play:

[image]